# Salesforce Surveys no "Advanced Settings" for custom data mapping

Tags: survey

[The docs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.task_create_data_map.htm&type=5) say:

> In the Survey Builder, click Advanced Settings, and then select Survey Data Mapping.

But there is no Advanced Settings anywhere in the survey builder. Not in the dropdown, not in "default settings."

[image: bad salesforce]

My user has the System Administrator profile.

Comment: As mentioned in the document does your org have any of these licenses `Available with the Survey Response Pack, Feedback Management - Starter, and Feedback Management - Growth licenses`

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same I try these steps:

1. Create A permission Set for the User by which the surveys you want to send/test.
2. Scroll down and find System Permissions. Click that.
3. Inside System Permission try to find : "Salesforce Surveys Advanced Features". Make sure this feature is enabled, if not go to Edit > and select the checkbox against it. [This can surely help you to bring the advanced setting in the Surveys]
4. After this, go back to the permission set and search "manage Assignments"
5. Add assignments.
6. Select the users that you want to use this feature. > next.
7. Assign.
8. Done.

That's all ! I hope this answer will solve your problem.

Comment: I believe this is not available if you only have the Survey Response pack license